# Get substring between two spesific characters in python

Tags: python, string, special-characters

I am really confused that can't write a code that do this for me.
Look This is my string:

> a="hello | my friends| in | stack | over | flow"

I want to print "my friends" which is between first and second "|"
Please help me

Comment: `a.split('|')` may help.

Comment: yes but how to print text between first and second |? a.split('|')[0].split('|')[1] is not answering

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `string.split` function.

```
>>> a="hello | my friends| in | stack | over | flow"
>>> a.split('|')[1].strip()
'my friends'
```

`a.split('|')[1]` prints the element at index 1 from the list which was created by splitting the input according to `|`.

Comment: Its That. Thank You SO SO SO Much Sir